# Друзья, решаю задачу, не могу прописать основной алгоритм

Tags: c#

Пишу задачу, вот её описание

---

Вы решили провести эстафету на электросамокатах. Эстафета состоит из N этапов, каждый длиной ai километров (1 ≤ i ≤ N) У вас имеется бесконечное количество одноразовых аккумуляторов, каждый из которых может заправить электросамокат на K километров. Перед каждым этапом вы можете взять сколько угодно аккумуляторов с собой. В конце этапа вы должны сдать свои одноразовые аккумуляторы на переработку.
В процессе подготовки эстафеты выяснилось, что последовательно идущие этапы можно объединить в один этап. За счет этого вам может понадобиться меньше аккумуляторов. Тем не менее, нельзя объединять больше, чем M этапов подряд.

Напишите программу, которая определяет, какое максимальное число аккумуляторов можно сэкономить с помощью объединения этапов.

Формат входных данных
В первой строке заданы 3 натуральных числа N, M и K (N ≤ 10^6, M ≤ 10, K ≤ 10^8)
Во второй строке заданы N натуральных чисел ai (ai≤109).

Формат выходных данных
В первой строке выведите одно натуральное число F — на сколько можно сократить количество используемых аккумуляторов. Разумеется, F должно быть максимально возможным.
Во второй строке выведите одно натуральное число P — количество групп объединённых этапов.
Затем выведите сами группы в P строк — по 2 натуральных числа si и ci, где si — номер первого этапа в группе, а ci — количество этапов в группе. Все si должны идти в порядке возрастания, а ci не должно превосходить M. Если существует несколько оптимальных решений, разрешается вывести любое.

Замечание
В первом тесте вы можете объединить первые три этапа, тем самым потратив всего 1 аккумулятор вместо трех.
Во втором тесте видно, что по правилам нельзя объединить больше 3 этапов подряд, так что придется дважды объединять этапы.

Ввод

5 3 3

1 1 1 3 3

Вывод

2

1

1 3

---

```
 bool check = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Введите 1 строку");
            int[] arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToArray<int>();

            int N = arr[0];  //  количество этапов
            int K = arr[1];  //  на сколько км может заправить 1 аккум
            int M = arr[2];  //  сколько максимум этапов можно объединять

            int F = 0;  //  на сколько аккумов можно сократить
            int P = 0;  //  количество групп объединенных этапов


            if (N > Math.Pow(10, 6) || M > 10 || K > Math.Pow(10, 8)) check = false;  //  ограничения
            if (!check) Console.WriteLine("ERROR");

            Console.WriteLine("Введите 2 строку");
            int[] arr2 = Console.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToArray<int>();  //  протяженность каждого этапа

            if (arr2.Length != N) check = false;  //  ограничения

            for (var i = 0; i < arr2.Length; i++)
            {
                if (arr2[i] < 1 || arr2[i] > Math.Pow(10, 9)) check = false;  //  ограничения
            }
            if (check)  //  основной алгоритм
            {
                Dictionary<int, bool> enough = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
                int avg = arr2.Sum() / arr2.Length;

                Console.WriteLine(avg);

                for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine($"Этап - {i+1}\tРасстояние - {arr2[i]}");
                    if(arr2[i] < K)
                    {
                        enough.Add(arr2[i], true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        enough.Add(arr2[i], false);
                    }
                }

                foreach(var i in enough)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i.Key + " " + i.Value);
                }
            } 
            else
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
```

> Не могу продумать основную логику